# grouping adjacent similar substrings

Tags: c#

I am writing a program in which I want to  group the adjacent substrings, e.g ABCABCBC can be compressed as 2ABC1BC or 1ABCA2BC.

Among all the possible options I want to find the resultant string with the minimum length.

Here is code what i have written so far but not doing job. Kindly help me in this regard.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace EightPrgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the set of operations: ");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            char[] array = input.ToCharArray();
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            string temp = "";
            string firstTemp = "";
            foreach (var x in array)
            {

                if (temp.Contains(x))
                {
                    firstTemp = temp;
                    if (list.Contains(firstTemp))
                    {
                        list.Add(firstTemp);
                    }
                    temp = "";
                    list.Add(firstTemp);
                }
                else
                {
                    temp += x;
                }
            }
            /*foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }*/
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `please ignore my poor logic` after ignoring it, there is no code to answer, and your question turns into  *"write it for me"*

Comment: Can't this be done in this way?

Comment: Maybe, but it is just a start... you should improve it a lot....

Comment: @L.B Please tell me a little how should I do this. Please I will be really thankful to you just a little pseudo code or some helping material

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with recursion. I cannot give you a C# solution, since I do not have a C# compiler here, but the general idea together with a python solution should do the trick, too.

So you have an input string `ABCABCBC`. And you want to transform this into an advanced variant of [run length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) (let's called it *advanced RLE*).

My idea consists of a general first idea onto which I then apply recursion:

1. The overall target is to find the shortest representation of the string using *advanced RLE*, let's create a function `shortest_repr(string)`.
2. You can divide the string into a prefix and a suffix and then check if the prefix can be found at the beginning of the suffix. For your input example this would be:

   - (A, BCABCBC)
   - (AB, CABCBC)
   - (ABC, ABCBC)
   - (ABCA, BCBC)
   - ...
3. This input can be put into a function `shorten_prefix`, which checks how often the suffix starts with the prefix (e.g. for the prefix `ABC` and the suffix `ABCBC`, the prefix is only one time at the beginning of the suffix, making a total of 2 `ABC` following each other. So, we can compact this prefix / suffix combination to the output `(2ABC, BC)`.

   This function `shorten_prefix` will be used on each of the above tuples in a loop.
4. After using the function `shorten_prefix` one time, there still is a suffix for most of the string combinations. E.g. in the output `(2ABC, BC)`, there still is the string `BC` as suffix. So, need to find the shortest representation for this remaining suffix. Wooo, we still have a function for this called `shortest_repr`, so let's just call this onto the remaining suffix.

This image displays how this recursion works (I only expanded one of the node after the 3rd level, but in fact all of the orange circles would go through recursion):

[image: Recursion call stack]

We start at the top with a call of `shortest_repr` to the string `ABABB` (I selected a shorter sample for the image). Then, we split this string at all possible split positions and get a list of prefix / suffix pairs in the second row. On each of the elements of this list we first call the prefix/suffix optimization (`shorten_prefix`) and retrieve a shortened prefix/suffix combination, which already has the run-length numbers in the prefix (third row). Now, on each of the suffix, we call our recursion function `shortest_repr`.

I did not display the upward-direction of the recursion. When a suffix is the empty string, we pass an empty string into `shortest_repr`. Of course, the shortest representation of the empty string is the empty string, so we can return the empty string immediately.
When the result of the call to `shortest_repr` was received inside our loop, we just select the shortest string inside the loop and return this.

This is some quickly hacked code that does the trick:

```
def shorten_beginning(beginning, ending):                                       
    count = 1                                                                   
    while ending.startswith(beginning):                                         
        count += 1                                                              
        ending = ending[len(beginning):]                                        

    return str(count) + beginning, ending                                       


def find_shortest_repr(string):                                                                                                          
    possible_variants = []                                                      

    if not string:                                                              
        return ''                                                               

    for i in range(1, len(string) + 1):                                         
        beginning = string[:i]                                                  
        ending = string[i:]                                                     
        shortened, new_ending = shorten_beginning(beginning, ending)            

        shortest_ending = find_shortest_repr(new_ending)                        

        possible_variants.append(shortened + shortest_ending)                   

    return min([(len(x), x) for x in possible_variants])[1]                     

print(find_shortest_repr('ABCABCBC'))                                           
print(find_shortest_repr('ABCABCABCABCBC'))                                     
print(find_shortest_repr('ABCABCBCBCBCBCBC'))
```

### Open issues

I think this approach has the same problem as the [recursive levenshtein distance calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Recursive). It calculates the same suffices multiple times. So, it would be a nice exercise to try to implement this with dynamic programming.

Comment: If I understand your description, that's sort of a greedy approach to choosing the prefix, which won't be optimal for all cases. Say `ABABCDEBCDE`, your approach would make that `2ABCDEBCDE` while the optimum is `ABA2BCDE`?

Comment: Just tested it, it yields `1ABA2BCDE` (the numeric prefix is needed for each substring to ensure unambiguousness). Maybe I did not highlight the loop in my recursion function well enough, I hope the image clarifies it a bit. I try all split points in the string and for each suffix again search for the shortest representation. Thus, it is possible to detect that `1ABA + shortest_repr(BCDEBCDE)` is shorter than `2ABC + shortest_repr(DEBCDE)`.

Comment: right, my mistake. I thought u only proceed with the best split point at each step in the recursion

Comment: thanks for your work for me bro. thank you so much... i will try to understand this though it seems difficult to me

Answer (score 0):

If this is not a school assignment or performance critical part of the code, [`RegEx`](https://regex101.com/r/roBEmS/1) might be enough:

```
string input = "ABCABCBC";
var re = new Regex(@"(.+)\1+|(.+)", RegexOptions.Compiled); // RegexOptions.Compiled is optional if you use it more than once
string output = re.Replace(input, 
    m => (m.Length / m.Result("$1$2").Length) + m.Result("$1$2")); // "2ABC1BC" (case sensitive by default)
```